# gradle: groovy command line - grep

Tags: git, gradle, groovy, command, line

I've got a method that counts all the tags in a branch:

```
def method = { ->
try {
    def code = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'tag', '--list'
        standardOutput = code
    }
    return code.toString().split("\n").size()
}
catch (ignored) {
    return -1;
}
}
```

I would like to change it in the way that it counts tags that contain a specific string. Unfortunately something like:

commandLine 'git', 'tag', '--list', '|', 'grep', 'keyword'

doesn't work as expected. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer question `why` remove `try-catch-ignore` or print the error stack trace before returning -1

---

as soon as pipe `|` is part of shell functionality, build the `commandline` like this:

```
commandLine "bash", "-c", "git tag --list | grep 'keyword'"
```

---

as alternative you can do filtering on the level of groovy:

```
return code.toString().split("\n").findAll{i-> i~='keyword'}.size()
```

here the `keyword` could be a regexp